# np.dot - weights are not being applied to inputs

Tags: numpy, matrix, vector

Trying to use np.dot function to multiply annual returns with weights in a portfolio to return portfolio performance

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
y_symbols = ['PG','MSFT', 'F', 'GE']
from datetime import datetime
startdate = datetime(1995,1,3)
enddate = datetime(2017,3,24)
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(y_symbols, start =startdate, end =enddate)['Adj Close']

returns = (data/data.shift(1)) - 1


annual_returns = returns.mean() * 252
annual_returns
F       0.118506
GE      0.127551
MSFT    0.197452
PG      0.129486
dtype: float64

weights = np.array([0.4, 0.4, 0.15, 0.05])

np.dot = (annual_returns, weights)

(F       0.118506
 GE      0.127551
 MSFT    0.197452
 PG      0.129486
 dtype: float64,
 array([0.4, 0.4, 0.15, 0.05])
```

Would expect to see one average of annual return for each stock * weighting

Any idea why I am not seeing one average here?

Comment: Non-reproducible; we need to see `annual_returns`

Comment: See below

annual returns is the returns for each stock over the specified period below


annual_returns = returns.mean() * 252

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(y_symbols, start =startdate, end =enddate)['Adj Close']

returns = (data/data.shift(1)) - 1

Comment: That's not particularly helpful - you then just introduce more unknown symbols. See documentation for MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what's that `np.dot=...` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Multiply annual returns with portfolio weighting of each stock to return portfolio performance.

Would expect to see one average instead of average for each stock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the np.dot value to a tuple. You should be making a function call instead by calling np.dot(annual_returns, weights)